# FlutterFirebaseCorePlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, dart-pub, flutter-packages

Ok so I run my program without importing firebase core, firebase auth and cloud firestore, and my code runs just fine but I register my app with firebase and it still runs fine but as soon as I import `Firebase_auth`, `Firebase_core` and `cloud_Firestore`... I get the following error

```
Note: C:\appflutter\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_core-0.7.0\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\core\FlutterFirebaseCorePlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\appflutter\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\cloud_firestore-0.16.0\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\firestore\streamhandler\TransactionStreamHandler.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
D8: Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file (# methods: 89543 > 65536)
com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: 
The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K.
```

Please help me.

Comment: Post `pubspec.yaml` and `build.gradle`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I was having the same problem today and I found the solution [here](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/1401) on Github

First, get the latest versions of your dependencies from [pub.dev](https://pub.dev)

Current latest versions are these:

1. `firebase_auth: ^0.20.0+1`
2. `firebase_core: ^0.7.0`

Then run these 3 commands in the terminal:

```
$ flutter pub upgrade

$ flutter pub get

$ flutter clean
```

And then run your project

```
$ flutter run
```

This will hopefully help you.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Which Dart SDK do you use?

Comment: This doesn't help me too. any other solutions please?
     minSdkVersion 27
     targetSdkVersion 30
     compileSdkVersion 30

Flutter version 2.2.0

dependencies:

  firebase_core: ^1.2.0
  firebase_messaging: ^10.0.0
  flutter_local_notifications: ^5.0.0+4

Error

   g\firebase_core-1.2.0\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\core\FlutterFirebaseCorePlugin.java:71: warning: [deprecation] Registrar in PluginRegistry has been deprecated
      public static void registerWith(PluginRegistry.Registrar registrar) {

Comment: This worked for me. When I ran the first three commands I got several errors throughout my project. but with "flutter run" everything has been fixed. Thanks!

Comment: Didn't 100% fix the issue, but taught me some stuff and got me there. Thank you!

Answer (score 13):

Seems it is a bug in Firebase plugins: https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/3876. However setting min SDK to 23 does not show the warning.

Comment: It's not about not showing the warning, it's about how to admit minSdk 16 or higher without getting rid of the firebase support.

Comment: I mean in SDK 23 or later it does not give that error.

Comment: updated SDK to 23 in `android>app>build.gradle` and it helped.

Answer (score 10):

it worked for me to change my sdkVersion to 23:

just go to android>app>build.gradle and
change the minSdkVersion-line in defaultConfig{} to .. `minSdkVersion 23`

Answer (score 4):

```
$ flutter pub get
```

Just Do it in your Terminal it will work

Answer (score 4):

Enable `multidex` in android project & run again.
I am suggesting this according to the last part of the error message you've posted.

According to this guide: https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/installation/android#enabling-multidex

> However, if your minSdkVersion is set to 20 or lower, then you must use the multidex support library and make the following modifications to your app project

Comment: For mine I was missing this even though I had multiDexEnabled true: `dependencies {
  implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3`
}'

Answer (score 2):

In android - app - build.gradel file

1. add - `implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'`  in dependencies section
2. add - multiDexEnabled true  in default config section [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CSNvK.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FI9tk.png)

Comment: Thank you, that finally solved the issue for me!

Answer (score 2):

Suffered the error of **FlutterFirebaseCorePlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API**. for two days.
finally solved it by changing minSdkVersion to 21 in app/build.gradle and run the app with **flutter run --no-sound-null-safety**.

Found that the error comes from the sound null safety implementation which grey lists all incompatible API

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues here, -Xlint and multidex.

For **-Xlint**, @Sarib's solution worked for me and both the -Xlint errors disappeared after running `flutter pub upgrade`, `flutter pub get` and `flutter clean`. You can find them under Tools > Flutter in Android Studio if you are not familiar with Terminal.

For **multidex**, according to the Android Studio [User Guide](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex), multidex is enabled by default if your minSdkVersion is 21 or higher. While @Joshi suggests [enabling multidex](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/installation/android/#enabling-multidex), I think it is simpler to update the `minSdkVersion` in android/app/build.gradle file to 21 or higher, rather than mess with more variables and adding more dependencies, assuming you're building an app that targets Android21 or higher.

Answer (score 1):

For this error:

Note: locationInD\flutter\plugins\firebase\core\FlutterFirebaseCorePlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

The solution I found was to replace this line in android/app/build.gradle:

`implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'`

with

`implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'`

Comment: For me works when i change this and enable multidex

https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/installation/android/#enabling-multidex

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and combined two suggested fixes to get it to finally work:

**minSdkVersion** 21, change to 23
**run** "flutter pub upgrade"
= **issues fixed!**

**To double-check what the fix was:**

I also reverted back to 21 and invalidated + flutter clean and the issue appeared again. Then I changed to 23 and the warnings disappeared!

Answer (score 0):

For me i changed one of my implementation version from
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:27.1.0') to

implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.6.0')
at the moment there are some bugs in this current version "27.1.0" and after running the application it worked

//To help someone my project needed this implementation for my ads #admob

Answer (score 0):

change to  minSdkVersion 24
in android/app/build.gradle

```
dependencies {
//add this in your dependencies
    implementation "androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.0"
}
```

then

```
$ flutter clean
$ flutter run
```

Comment: you do not need to go for 24 just setting minSdkVersion 21 also works

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing this error means your app has a minSdk of API 20 or lower and your app and the libraries it references exceed 65,536 methods.

`These error conditions display a common number: 65536`

To learn more about why this error occurs reference the following [Link][1]

[1]: https://developer.android.com/build/multidex#groovy:~:text=Android%20app%20(APK,your%20own%20code.

**To fix this** you can by changing `minSdkVersion to >=21` in `app/build.gradle`

(This will enabled multidex by default and you don't need the multidex library.)

**Otherwise**, you can keep `minSdkVersion <=20` and modify your `app/build.gradle` as follows:

```
    android {
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 15 
        targetSdkVersion 33
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    ...
}

dependencies {
    implementation "androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1"
}
```

*Use latest version of multidex.*

**If the program asks for enabling multidex**, you can do it manually using the following command:

```
flutter run --debug
```

When prompted, enter `y`.

To learn more about why this error occurs reference the following :
https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#enabling-multidex-support

After this **you might encounter** `Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(null-error, Host platform returned null) firebase`

To solve this follow the following youtube video guide: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qn2ysnVMvEE

Answer (score -1):

Check your minSDK, it works fine for 23